# Python: Average of items in matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix

We have a code like this at our school as a home assignment. The code need to be done in python 2, because of an school made app:

Write a function average(m), which receives a matrix containing integer items as argument. The function calculates and returns the average of the items in the matrix.

Below is the code given:

```
def test():
    l = []
    for i in range(random.randint(3,5)):
        ll = []
        for j in range(random.randint(3,4)):
            ll.append(random.randint(1,10))
        l.append(ll)
    print ("Matrix:",l)
    print ("Average of items:", average(l))

test()
print ("")
test()

import random
```

I tried doing this:

```
def average(m):

lst = []
average = sum(lst) / len(lst)
 return average
```

But it comes back with:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

I've tried to find solutions for making lists join another, but I have not been able to make any use of the help that is provided in the web. Appreciate any help that is given, thank you.

Comment: Yes. This was my last resort. :) Couldn't find anything related on this. So I asked help of people who know better than me.

Comment: but the help you would get from here is help from the web which you are not allowed to make use of?

Comment: I meant that I haven't been able to make use any of the help given on the internet :))))))

Comment: I can use the internet for the project yes.

Comment: How does your variable `lst` relate to the list of lists `m` which is passed to `average`? It seems that you are simply ignoring the function input in favor of an empty list that you define, which makes no sense at all. Why not loop over `m` row by row, forming row sums as you go along?

Comment: how do you loop over m row by row? It hasn't been taught to us.

Comment: Just loop over `m` -- it is a list of lists, thought of as a list of rows. Presumably you have been taught how to loop over a list.

Comment: Ty a lot, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic manual approach is a nested loop to collect total and count:

```
def average(m):
    total = count = 0
    for row in m:
        for val in row:
            count += 1
            total += val
    return total / count
```

Of course there are utils to achieve this in fewer lines:

```
def average(m):
    return sum(map(sum, m)) / sum(map(len, m))
```

Comment: Nice `utils` for this problem.  It'll be nicer to elaborate the `map` part for the beginner(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy as that works with N dimensional arrays.

The Python built in average function (to date) can only work with one dimensional iterables.

You have to iterate over the rows in your array to sum the columns, e.g.

```
import random

def test():
    l = []
    for i in range(random.randint(3, 5)):
        ll = []
        for j in range(random.randint(3,4)):
            ll.append(random.randint(1,10))
        l.append(ll)

    return l

def average(ll):
    s = n = 0
    for l in ll:
        s += sum(l)
        n += len(l)

    return s/n

res = test()

print ("Matrix:", res)
print ("Average of items:", average(res))
```